# Cannot insert new entity with class table inheritance (Doctrine 2.2)

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, class-table-inheritance

I am using the class table inheritance pattern with Doctrine 2.2.  My DB schema is as follows:

**Parent**
access_id (primary key)
access_type (discriminator column)
access_role
access_acl
access_primary
user_id (foreign key)

**Child 1**
access_id (foreign key)
account_id (foreign key)

**Child 2**
access_id (foreign key)
distributor_id (foreign key)

When I try to insert a new entity into the database, the parent query looks okay, but the child query has an extra parameter.  When I dumped the query being executed, this is what I saw:

```
INSERT INTO user_access_account (access_id, account_id) VALUES (?, ?)   
array('1'=> 39, '2'=> NULL, '3'=> 3 )
```

The '2' index is extraneous.  '1' => 39, '2' => 3 are the correct parameters.

The code used to execute this query is as follows:

```
$entity = new Entity\UserAccessAccount();
$entity->setAccount($account)
       ->setUser($user)
       ->setAccessRole($accessRole)
       ->setAccessAcl($accessAcl)
       ->setAccessPrimary($accessPrimary);

$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush($entity);
```

Comment: Can you post how exactly you're creating query?

Comment: @devdRew Thanks for the response.  I posted the code you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the auto-generated entity mapping had some data that needed to be deleted.  The `oneToOne` definition from `UserAccessAccount` back to `UserAccess` caused Doctrine to believe there was an extra parameter.  It makes sense now!

**Correct:**

```
Entity\UserAccessAccount:
  type: entity
  table: user_access_account
  repositoryClass: Repository\UserAccessAccount
  oneToOne:
    account:
      targetEntity: Entity\Account
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: null
      inversedBy: null
      joinColumns:
        account_id:
          referencedColumnName: account_id
      orphanRemoval: false
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Incorrect:**

```
Entity\UserAccessAccount:
  type: entity
  table: user_access_account
  repositoryClass: Repository\UserAccessAccount
  oneToOne:
    account:
      targetEntity: Entity\Account
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: null
      inversedBy: null
      joinColumns:
        account_id:
          referencedColumnName: account_id
      orphanRemoval: false
    userAccess:
      targetEntity: Entity\UserAccess
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: null
      inversedBy: null
      joinColumns:
        access_id:
          referencedColumnName: user_access
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```